# Drawing an HS tableau

Tags: tables, multirow, linguistics, border, phonetic

I want to draw a tableau like this picture.
OT tableau package is not helpful in this case. Don't care about the phonetics symbols. Just write it with a,b,c and 1,2,3 the columns and rows.
[image: HS tableau]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Which picture?

Comment: I uploaded the picture in the question body

Comment: Do you see a picture there? I don't.

Comment: Me too. I dont see any picture in the question.

Comment: I think OP refers to the table itself, that it's inserted as image, not as table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what HS tableaux are; definitely over my head. But the column, row structure can be recreated in a variety of ways. Here's my attempt using the [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en) package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}% font choice; use whatever
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% font-choice; use whatever
\usepackage{tipa}% for \textdyoghlig
\usepackage{tabularray} % for table

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]

\emph{Harmonic improvement in} \textless na.\textdyoghlig{}zum.to, na.\textdyoghlig{}zuN.to, na.\textdyoghlig{}zun.to\textgreater\\[0.3\baselineskip]
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=3pt,colsep=3pt} % padding between cells
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec = {rlcccc}, % column alignments
    hline{1,2,5} = {0.7pt}, % full solid lines above+below title row and at bottom
    vline{1,3,7} = {0.7pt}, % full solid lines left+right first column and at end
    hline{3,4} = {3-6}{0.4pt}, % thinner solid lines between rows
    vline{4,6} = {0.4pt}, % thinner solid lines between columns
    vline{5} = {0.4pt,dashed} % dashed vertical line in middle
}
\SetCell[c=2]{l}{ /na\textdyoghlig{}zum-to/ } & & \textsc{CodaCond} & \textsc{HavePlace} & \textsc{Max}[Place] & \textsc{NoLink}[Place] \\
a.& {na\textdyoghlig{}zum.to\\ \emph{is less harmonic than}} & \texttt{*}! & & & \\
b.& {na\textdyoghlig{}zuN.to\\ \emph{is less harmonic than}} & & \texttt{*}! & \texttt{*} & \\
c.& na\textdyoghlig{}zun.to & & & \texttt{*} & \texttt{*}
\end{tblr}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: HS Tableau output]

Comment: Thanks a lot
It was exactly what I needed.